# How do i get a list of nearby users in an react native app based on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app based on **Maps**, with react native and Firebase as a backend, And I'm Stuck with **Nearby users Feature**,
I'm using react native maps for Geolocation, and react native firebase.

Now In my app, I have **two types of users** ( *End User, Provider* ) and when registered I'm saved Data about them contain their Location ( Lat, Long ),
at the moment I'm working with End User App, and I save some faked Data about providers ( Location ), and I don't have an idea about how to get all of the provider nearby of my location,

Here's my DB [Providers]

[image: Provider]

Here's My Code To Get the current location to users, and I've tried some Queries to get the nearby providers but it's Fall :(, I can easily get all provider but bot the nearby 
so ..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const LATITUDE = 50.78825;
const LONGITUDE = 51.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.0421;

class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            width: width,
            marginBottom: 1,
            region: {
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            }
        };

    }
    requestLocationPermission = async () => {
        const LocationPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            // , {
            //     'message': 'This App needs to Access your location, OK?'
            // }
        )
        if (LocationPermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                //Will give you the current location
                position => {
                    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;

                    this.setState({
                        region: {
                            latitude,
                            longitude,
                            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                        }
                    })
                },
                error => alert(error.message),
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
            );
            this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
                console.log(position);
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;

                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.requestLocationPermission()
    };
    render() {
        const { region } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={[styles.map, { width: this.state.width }]}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    onMapReady={() => console.log(this.state.region)}
                    showsUserLocation
                    region={region}
                    loadingEnabled={true}
                    // style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    textStyle={{ color: '#bc8b00' }}
                    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#BC8B00' }}
                >
                    <Marker
                        coordinate={this.state.region}
                        title="Hello Title"
                        description="description..."
                    />
                </MapView>
                {/* <Text>{this.state.region.latitude}</Text> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 30,
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: -1,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    },
});

export default Map;
```

If anyone interested to help me here is my 
[Repo](https://github.com/anastely/khadamati_App)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am trying to create firebase function to handle it but no success so far...

Comment: Hello @David , I solve it immediately by using [@turf/distance](https://turfjs.org/docs/) in FrontEnd not in firebase cloud function

Comment: Can you please share some code so I could understand how I can handle it on my end? Thanks

Comment: So you fetch the all users and then apply the filtering? I want to fetch only users which are near to me ...

Comment: Yes, the main idea is fetching all users then make filtering to get all users based on my location and how much KM nearby of me "I sent this comment from mobile I will add code later"

Comment: Ah ok I see @DevAs. For my case, I need fetch the near users only from DB

Comment: Hello @David how can I chat with u? If u have a Twitter account let me know, we will explain this together

Comment: I don't have Twitter a/c. But I have FB, if it is ok for you

Comment: @David ok send me the link, and I will talk with u today:)

Comment: Let's have a discussion on LinkedIn, it is much more suiatble for me, thanks :)  https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-voskanyan-phd-1a1294142/

Comment: @David i sent ..

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/latlon-geohash geohash converts latlong to a set of charachters and the length of the string is dependent on the precision you select